# How to print a message in error handling with try, throw and catch

Tags: sql-server-2008, error-handling

I want to print a message ("The table employe is not exist in database") in my query.

My query is:

```
create proc sp_emprecord
as 
begin
    select * from employe
end

begin try
    execute sp_emprecord
end try

begin catch
    select
    error_message() as errormessage,
    error_number() as erronumber,
    error_state() as errorstate,
    error_procedure() as errorprocedure,
    error_line() as errorline;
 end catch
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
create proc sp_emprecord
as 
begin
    select * from employe
end
go
begin try
    execute sp_emprecord
end try

begin catch
    if(ERROR_NUMBER() = 208)
        RAISERROR ('The table employe is not exist in database', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    else
        select
        error_message() as errormessage,
        error_number() as erronumber,
        error_state() as errorstate,
        error_procedure() as errorprocedure,
        error_line() as errorline;
 end catch
```